# Slow iteration through pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas

I am iterating through a pandas dataframe and outputting in a text file. However, it seems to be really slow (number of rows in dataframe ~80,000). Is there a way to speed it up?

```
for count, row in df.iterrows():
    print idx
    idx += 1

    # Extract data
    sid = row['ID']
    val = row['VALUE_']
    slp = row['Slope']

    if(slp <= 20):
        out_file.write('{0:10d} "InputFiles//data//{1:d}.sol"\n'.format(sid,val))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can subset the data using [Boolean indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) rather than looping through the rows:

```
subset_df = df[df['slp'] <= 20]
```

Then you can loop over this subsetted df to write it out using your function.